# Storyboard navigation from normal view to NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have a normal ViewController i want to navigate in my **NavigationViewController**, this **NavigatioViewController** can capture photos, but i receive black screen:

```
@interface OtherCollectionViewController ()

-(void)add
{
    TakePhotoViewController* takePhoto=[[TakePhotoViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:takePhoto animated:YES completion:nil];




}
```

TakePhotoViewController is embed in **NavigationViewController** and checks if the device have camera, this with navigation through the Xcode worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance from your TakePhotoViewController. If you're working with storyboard, use the Storyboard ID from the NavigationController.

```
- (void)add
{
    UINavigationController *yourNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNavigationControllerStoryboardID"];
    [self presentViewController:yourNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

That's all